# NancyFX, extension method for HtmlHelpers<T> is not recognised in Razor view

Tags: razor, nancy

I am trying to create an extension method for HtmlHelpers<T> using NancyFX.

The code is something like this

```
  public static IHtmlString DropdownList<T>(HtmlHelpers<T> htmlHelper, string elementId,     string elementName, IEnumerable<DropdownListItem> dropdownListItems)
  {
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (dropdownListItems != null && dropdownListItems.ToList().Any())
    {
        dropdownListItems.ToList().ForEach(t => builder.AppendFormat(@"<option value=""{0}"" {1}>{2}</option>", t.Value, t.Selected ? "selected" : string.Empty, t.Text));
    }

    var htmlMarkup = string.Format(@"<select id=""{0}"" name=""{1}"">{2}</select>", elementId, elementName, builder);
    return new NonEncodedHtmlString(htmlMarkup);
  }
```

This method is not recognised in cshtml view. I have tried both with namespace and without.
When using namespace, I have registered it in razor section in web.config.

NancyFX version I am using: 0.16.1.0

Any working example on how to use extension methods with razor views in NancyFX will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh fogged it! Rookie error. There's a tiny mistake in the extension method. Missed keyword **this** for the first parameter.